# ASP.NET MVC action method returns JSON data without quotes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. My action method returns JSON data:

```
public JsonResult ReturnJson()
{
    return Json(new { stringValue = "Value", intValue = 123, boolValue = true });
}
```

And the returned value doesn't have quotes around property names and values, except string value:

**`{boolValue: true, intValue: 123, stringValue: "Value"}`**

Calling `$.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()` throws exception:

[image]

It doesn't matter if I pass normal object or anonymous one. When I parse a string with quotes, it works correctly. What is wrong with my action method?

Comment: You don't need to use either `$.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()`

Comment: your result is already in JSON. you are not returning string.

Comment: That's right, thank you.